# Running Python script from VBA, checking to see if 'RetVal = Shell' command is working

Tags: python, excel, vba, shell

**Original Question**

When I go into C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts and click EbayWebScraper.py the script runs. It takes about 30 seconds but the output is correct.

I want to run this script from within Excel / VBA. I tried using the code 'RetVal = Shell' and writing it in 6 different ways. After the 6 failed attempts, I turned the code into comments.

```
Sub Python()

'RetVal = Shell("python.exe C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py", vbNormalFocus)


'RetVal = Shell("C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe " & "C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py")

'RetVal = Shell("C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py")

'RetVal = Shell("C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py", vbNormalFocus)


'RetVal = Shell("python.exe" & "C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py", vbNormalFocus)

'RetVal = Shell("python.exe" & "C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py")


End Sub
```

Do I need to slow the VBA macro down somehow? Is it a case of the VBA macro working too quickly and not giving the Python script enough time?

I read this [VBA Macro running too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117587/vba-macro-running-too-fast) and experimented with

```
Application Wait (Now + TimeValue (0:00:10")).
```

Unfortunately the experiment did not seem to work.

I use Loom to record the screen and then I play back the recording and have a better look at any error messages that appear in CMD. Unfortunately to the best of my knowledge every error message I have occurred, I have now fixed.

**Update 1**

I don't know if I am being really stupid. To the best of my knowledge I have provided the right file directory. The link 'Windows Explorer File Directory' is for a screenshot I took.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\HP>python C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>
```

[Windows Explorer File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs6Wc.png)

**Update 2**

This also failed.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\HP>Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py
'Documents\Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**Update 3**

When I ran this code (which I got from [Wait for Shell to finish, then format cells - synchronously execute a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells-synchronously-execute-a-command)) -

```
Sub Python2()

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Dim errorCode As Long

errorCode = wsh.Run("C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

If errorCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Done! No error to report."
Else
    MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
End If

End Sub
```

I got the error -

Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)':
Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3' failed

**Update 4**

I am looking at [Error running Shell object / commands through Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267283/error-running-shell-object-commands-through-excel-vba).

**Update 5**

This code finally worked (I got the code from the link in Update 4).

```
    Sub Python3()

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Dim errorCode As Long

errorCode = wsh.Run(Chr(34) & "C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts" & "\EbayWebScraper.py" & Chr(34))

If errorCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Done! No error to report."
Else
    MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells-synchronously-execute-a-command

Comment: Just out of curiosity if you use `python C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\EbayWebScraper.py` directly in command prompt does it run?  Some of these fail because the formatting doesn't have spaces. Calling python.exe without being in the correct directory will also likely fail. Your second and third examples look relatively correct.

Comment: I have updated the bottom of my question.